# Сколько букв «н» в слове «рассказано»?

Tags: грамматика

«Не все еще сказки рассказаны» — почему в слове «рассказаны» 1 «н»?

Answer (score 2):

> **§ 100.** Краткие формы страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишутся с одним **н**, напр.: *читан, читана, читано, читаны;
>   прочитан, прочитана, прочитано, прочитаны; мечен, мечена, мечено,
>   мечены; помечен, помечена, помечено, помечены.* Так же пишутся формы
>   среднего рода в безличном употреблении, напр.: *накурено, насорено,
>   езжено, хожено, езжено-переезжено, хожено-перехожено.*

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=54#pp54